# How to prevent widget's size changing in Kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, widget, size, kivy, python-3.4

I've been playing with [this](http://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/firstwidget.html) code and I've found some (probably) strange thing: when I add parent to my class, size changes to [100, 100] (see comments):

```
from random import random, randint

import kivy

kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line, Ellipse, Triangle, Rectangle


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(random(), 1, 1, mode='hsv')
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(self.width - touch.x, self.height - touch.y))
            print(self.width, self.height)  # It works OK if I return painter below, but it's not if I return parent.

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [self.width - touch.x, self.height - touch.y]


class Example(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        painter = MyPaintWidget()
        print(painter.size)  # Shows [100, 100] anyway.
        parent.add_widget(painter)
        return parent  # If I return painter, everything works as I want (except painter.size still shows [100, 100]).


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Example().run()
```

Why does that happen? And how should I make it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(100, 100)` is the default size for widgets. In this case your painter has that size because you never set it to anything else.

Even if its parent were a layout class that would automatically move and resize the painter, its size would still read (100, 100) at this point because the layout hasn't had time to run yet. You shouldn't generally worry about the pixel values at this point - if you need something else to depend on them, use a binding to update the other thing automatically when the first one changes. This is made particularly easy by kv language.

Comment: So how do I get window's size and set it for widget (e.g. without kv language)?

Comment: You can use `kivy.core.window.Window.size`. However, you probably don't really want to do this, and would be better off making your root widget a layout class that will automatically resize the child - e.g. a `BoxLayout`.

Comment: How to get Layout's size if I've never assigned it? `self.size` still says (100, 100).

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I've created Layout inside BoxLayout between some widgets, in kv: `size_hint_x: None` and `width: self.height` (actual size is 900 × 900 and changes after resize), but `print(self.size)` still says (100, 100).

Comment: The question is how to get it? I've unsuccessfully tried to find smth else in docs.

Comment: Please post a separate question with a working code example of exactly what you're trying, along with what you expect, and how that differs from what you see.

Comment: [Here it is.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792518/how-can-i-get-widgets-layouts-actual-size-in-kivy)